# What frictionless cube towers are possible?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, puzzle

Assume you are building towers out of identical frictionless cubes of constant density on a flat frictionless surface.  The rules of the tower are that there may only be a single cube that does not support any other cubes (only one cube on the top layer, all other cubes support that top cube), if any cube other than this top cube is removed the tower will topple (the tower is minimal), and the supporting cubes may not be the only support for another cube (lower levels must be larger than higher levels).  These rules imply that if one is required to use $n$ cubes, not all values of $n$ permit an acceptable tower.  The case of $n=1,3,4,6$ are all possible, as demonstrated in the image below.  The cases of $n=2,5$ are not possible (I am fairly certain).  My question is for what values of $n$ may one build an acceptable tower?

[image: Demonstration of acceptable towers with n=1,3,4,6.]

Comment: Well, we know the solution set is infinite because all triangular numbers work.

Comment: @OscarLanzi, we also know that if $T$ is a triangle number greater than 1, $n=T+1$ and $n=T+2$ also work.  After that I am not sure what to do.

Comment: Not for $n=3+2$. In any event we have evidence that all numbers work except $2$ and $5$, see the answer (and my comments to it).

Comment: I do not see why $5$ is not possible, with three layers $1+2+2$, where the bottom cubes each support a corner of one of the cubes in the middle layer and part of the other diagonal of the other cube in the middle layer (though not its centre).  This would conflict with your "(lower levels must be larger than higher levels)" assertion but I do not see this as a necessary consequence of your "supporting cubes may not be the only support for another cube" condition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only $2$ and $5$ are not possible.

Clearly every triangular number is possible. You can build a triangle just like your $n=6$ example, where each layer is a row that contains one fewer cubes than the row below it.

In such a triangular tower with 3 or more blocks on the bottom row, any of the bottom row blocks can be replaced by two blocks. If the bottom row block being replaced is in the middle supporting two blocks above it, then place the replacement blocks such that each supports only one of the two blocks at a corner. That ensures minimality. Once all of the middle blocks of the bottom row are replaced by two, you can replace each end block by two arranged just like the $n=4$ case example. In this way you can add blocks one by one until the entire bottom row is doubled. If you then add one more cube you have reached the next triangular number, so you can put all those extra cubes and your new cube together to form a new base row.

Here is how it looks when a base row of 5 blocks supporting a row of 4 blocks is doubled to 10 blocks:

[image]

This procedure works for any triangular tower with 3 or more blocks on the bottom row, so from $6$ cubes onwards.

As Oscar Lanzi points out, this does not work on a tower with only 2 blocks in the bottom row, because then you would have a single block being supported by 4 others, which cannot be minimal. So the only numbers that are not possible are $2$ and $5$.

Comment: I am not sure of this. If there are five cubes then we have to have four supporting the fifth one. If we then remove a bottom cube, leaving three in that layer, how do we guarantee the tower always topples?

Comment: @OscarLanzi I have added a picture to make it clearer.

Comment: Still not working for $n=5$. Need two cubes in the next to bottom layer to set your structure up. Thus apparently $n\in(\mathbb N-\{2,5\})$.

Comment: @OscarLanzi You are correct. I overlooked the fact that my doubling procedure needs interior blocks on the bottom row, so only works from 6 onwards.